# Removing spaces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got problems when I upload a htaccess to my server:

The layout .css doesn't load. I've put my css in the dir css `/css/style.css` and using `href="../css/style.css"` to load it.

I've got a page `/category.php?nameid=Test&id=test%20lekker` as you see there is a `%20` I tried to replace it with a `-` but it doesn't show anything from mysql.
I want to replace a space to - test-lekker

Also I've tried to get `/category.php?nameid=Test&id=test%20lekker` to `site/Test/test%20` but its not working.

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^detail/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /category.php?nameid=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If your page is `/category.php` and your css is `/css/style.css` then why are you linking to `../css/style.css`?

Comment: Can you please explain what you would like to do with the spaces? Do your ID's in the database contain space or hyphen?

Comment: You need to explain better what is not working and show the code you already have.

Comment: can you show your htaccess working file..

Comment: updated added my htaccess

Comment: @akirk I just need for now to remove %20 in the url and replace it with - or what ever..

Comment: @user3490572 - have a look at `urldecode`

Comment: Also, you .htaccess only allows a single slash in the URL. You need to modify it to match more slashes.

Comment: @slugonamission I new to this .htaccess I don't know where to begin with the slash to add.

Comment: Make sure css is linked as `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: @anubhava Just made my htaccess simple but the second one doesn't work `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ category.php?nameID=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?nameid=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
`

Comment: Did you make css change as I suggested? What other problem did you get?